# Propiedades definidas en, #id vs .clase

Tags: css, css3

Tengo una duda en el uso de `div` y `.class`.

Tengo un documento HTML5 con varios `div`. La cuestión es que el `div` tiene unas propiedades CSS definidas y yo pretendo modificarlas mediante una clase. Al intentarlo compruebo que cuando defino un valor para una propiedad en la clase, si previamente está definida esa misma propiedad en el `div`, el valor no cambia a menos que a la propiedad definida en la clase la acompañe del hack `!important`.

Me gustaría saber por qué sucede esto y si sucede, o no, con todas las propiedades que utilice. Y por último, ¿qué ocurre con la compatibilidad entre `#id`y `div`, y entre `div`y `.class`.

Comment: Quizá esta pregunta te ayude también a resolver tus dudas: [¿Qué es y para que se utiliza la especificidad de CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%c3%a9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css/122040#122040)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para determinar el valor del atributo, el navegador necesita reglas. Es la  **precedencia** de una regla frente a otra.

Hay 2 factores principales...

#### El orden de precedencia de los selectores:

Esta una de las partes mas importantes de CSS y que explica lo que estas observando. 
Los distintos tipos de selectores tienen distinta precedencia.

El orden es:

```
!important >> style="attr: valor" >> #id >> .clase >> div
```

Detallado:

1. El uso de `!important`: cualquier regla con `!important` gana sobre todas las demás y siempre se aplica, salvo que dos reglas incluyan `!important` en cuyo caso, se aplican las otras reglas para determinar cual es el valor del atributo.
2. Atributo `style` del elemento, o `<div style="color: red;">`, lo que especifiques aquí toma precedencia sobre cualquier otro estilo en un archivo `.css`, excepto por uno con `!important` (esto aplica a todos los demás casos).
3. Estilos establecidos por `#id`: los estilos como `#id { color: blue; }` son los mas importantes dentro de un `.css`.
4. Estilos establecidos por `.clase`: los estilos como `.clase { color: white; }` el caballito de batalla del `.css`, pues están en el medio del espectro y pueden ser fácilmente sobre-escritos por `#id` o como veremos luego por cantidad de coincidencias.
5. Por ultimo, `div` o elemento: establecer atributos por medio de `div { color: yellow; }` es lo menos precedente y se suele utilizarse para establecer valores por defecto.

Ejemplo:

```css
#id { background: yellow; }
.rojo { background: blue; }
div { background: red; }
.mata_a_todos { background: orange !important; }
```

```html
<div id="id" class="rojo mata_a_todos" style="background: green;">hola</div>
<div id="id" class="rojo" style="background: green;">hola</div>
<div id="id" class="rojo">hola</div>
<div class="rojo">hola</div>
<div>hola</div>
```

#### La cantidad de coincidencias

Considera que tienes un `div` con una clase y 3 reglas:

```css
div { background: black; }
div.rojo { background: red; }
.rojo { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="rojo">hola</div>
```

Aquí toma precedencia la segunda regla pues y tiene mas cantidad de coincidencias que cualquiera de las otras dos. Fíjate que el orden en que aparecen las reglas en el CSS no importa.

Estas son las reglas básicas de precedencia de CSS.

A instancias de @AlvaroMontoro, a estas reglas se las conoce como Especificidad CSS.

Comment: Muy buena la respuesta, solo echo en falta la palabra especificidad.

Comment: Muy buena la respuesta. Muchas gracias. Así se entiende todo mucho mejor.