# ¿ Como quitar hueco y hacer barra de navegación fija?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy creando una web con bootstrap y quería que la barra de navegación se quedara fija y no subiera al hacer scrool. También queda un pequeño hueco en la parte superior de esta barra que no se como quitar. No pongo el código bootstrap por que es muy extenso. Dejo una muestra de mi código a ver como puedo solucionar lo del hueco y la barra de navegación fija.
Gracias.
*EDITO LA PREGUNTA*
Esto es lo [lo que veo antes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsTXV.jpg) y esto lo que veo [despues de aplicar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP21n.jpg)  `#content{
    position: relative;
    top: 78px;
}`
No se si con esto podrán ayudarme, modifique el código varias veces, pero me paso de caracteres.

```css
body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 position: relative;
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLLX9.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7vbZ.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como estás usando Bootstrap, simplemente añádele la clase `.navbar-fixed-top` a tu `nav` para que la barra de navegación quede fija en la parte superior. Por lo tanto, deberías quitar la propiedad `position: relative` que tienes en tu clase `tm_navbar`.

Como quieres que el fondo de la barra de navegación sea otro distinto al de la barra de navegación podrás hacerlo haciendo uso de la **[especificidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)** de CSS (entre otras cosas para evitar utilizar `!important`), es decir, utilizando un estilo más específico que los que utiliza Bootstrap.

En este caso he utilizado la clase `negro` (tu podrías darle el nombre que quisieras) pero teniendo en cuenta varias clases anteriores para hacer el estilo mucho más específico que el que aplica Bootstrap a la clase `navbar-default`.

```
nav.navbar-default.negro{
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Además, el espacio que se te queda en la parte superior es debido a que el body tiene un margen por defecto. Simplemente añádele `margin: 0` a tu body y ese espacio desaparecerá.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0; /* NUEVO */
}

/* NUEVA CLASE */
nav.navbar-default.negro{
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 /* position: relative; */  /* ELIMINADO */ 
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top tm_navbar negro" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Francisco Romero , estoy probando todas las respuestas pues hasta ahora no funciona ninguna. Tu idea funciona en parte, la barra se queda fija pero sin color de fondo. Tengo que decirte que  tengo mas estilos que no añadí por exceso de espacio,podía ser un inconveniente. La versión de Bootstrap que utilizo es la 3.0.0.                                 Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Y  sigue quedando el hueco. Tengo que decirte que lo probé en la plantilla que cogí de ejemplo y si funciona, pero en el mio tengo mas estilos.                         Gracias @Francisco Romero.

Comment: @gemita He editado mi respuesta con una solución al tema del color del fondo. En este caso he usado el negro pero podrías utilizar cualquier color que quisieras agregarle. En cuanto al tema del espacio, temo decirte que si no editas la pregunta y nos muestras tal y como tienes los estilos, no podré ayudarte, ya que es prácticamente imposible adivinar como tienes tu HTML/CSS actualmente.

Comment: Gracias @Francisco Romero. Conseguí cubrir la barra de navegación. La cosa es que me guié de la [siguiente plantilla](https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51656.html). Yo quite la parte superior donde muestra el titulo **Jessica Becker** y ahora el navbar me tapa algo del carrusel de imágenes. No se como podía solucionar eso. Ya esta por buena la respuesta, pero seguiré intentando solucionarlo. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: @gemita Vale, te explico un poco lo que he hecho. Por un lado, he eliminado el panel morado y el `container` con el titulo de Jessica. Agregándole la clase `navbar-fixed-top` se ha quedado fija en la parte superior sin ningún tipo de espacio. Después, como al hacerla fija el contenido de la página se queda por debajo de ella (debido a que el navbar se sale del workflow de la página), lo que puedes hacer es bajar el contenido. Para ello, al div con `id="content"` le he agregado `position: relative` y `top: 78px` que es lo que ocupa el `navbar`. Espero haberme explicado bien :)

Comment: Te explicaste de maravilla, gracias de nuevo @Francisco Romero .

Comment: Bueno @Francisco Romero, esta perfecto, ahora me di cuenta que al hacer la ultima modificación me a estropeado el  el footer. Esto es increíble, se arregla una cosa y se rompe otra. Es una pena pero dejare el carrusel de imágenes mas pequeño, pues queda muy feo el footer, se le come la parte superior. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: @gemita Te recomiendo que, si lo necesitas, realices una nueva pregunta. Si no, en esta se empezarían a hacer ediciones sin parar y al final nos iríamos del tema principal (que era que el navbar se quedara fijo arriba y sin espacio) y podría confundir a futuros lectores que vengan en busca del mismo problema. Y de nada, es un placer ayudar en lo que se puede :)

Answer (score 3):

No he podido reproducir el problema y eso que inclui boostrap 3 con un cdn, sin embargo muchas veces se suele solucionar agregando `margin: 0` al navbar usando un selector con mayor prioridad como `body .menuheader .navbar`.

```css
body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}

body .menuheader .navbar{
  margin: 0;
}

/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 position: relative;
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo otro es que si quieres que no muestre espacio de separación a los lados, puedes agregar esto otro:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
grid.less:7
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez pero no me funciona, sigue el pequeño hueco, quizá es porque tengo mas estilos que no añadí por falta de sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar la clase **fixed-top** según

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement
```

Para que este estilo haga efecto debes asegurarte de que tu position este en fixed, por lo cuál en tu css debes quitar el position relative.

```
.tm_navbar {
position: relative;
padding: 26px 0 22px;
margin: 0;
background: none;
border: none;
```

}

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregar un estilo a tu barra de navegacion, por ejemplo (suponiendo que estes usando la clase .navbar.navbar-default):

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin: 0;

}
```

y agrega la clase .navbar-fixed-top a tu barra de navegacion.

Me cuentas como te fue.

Comment: No me funciona @julian olarte tengo que decir que tengo mas estilos aparte de los que puse en la pregunta, los cuales omití por no tener espacio.

Comment: veo que tu navbar tiene la clase "navbar-static-top", intenta cambiar esta por navbar-fixed-top

Comment: Gracias @julian olarte Eso ya lo cambie y tampoco funciona, tengo mas estilos que no puse por exceso de espacio. Ya no se que hacer, no encuentro solución.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo del hueco esta solucionado. Respecto a dejar la barra de navegación fija podrías hacer uso del Pluging de Bootstrap llamado Affix.
Te pongo un ejemplo a continuación de como funcionaría en tu ejemplo:
Habría que agregar en:

el **CSS**

```
.affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

  .affix + .container {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
```

en el **HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default tm_navbar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="30" role="navigation">
```

donde

> data-offset-top="30"

es la cantidad de pixeles que querés que haga scroll para que se fije. Éste es un atributo opcional.

> data-offset-bottom="30"

sería para fijarlo abajo.
Y si no se coloca este atributo, el nav quedaría fijo al cargar la web.
Sirve tanto para utilizarlo horizontal o verticalmente.

Faltaría limpiar un poco el código que por falta de tiempo no pude.

Éxitos.