# ¿Por qué mi pagina web no visualiza las propiedades que escribo en css?

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner estas propiedades

```css
h2{
 text-align: center;
}
 p {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  }
```

Pero ya en mi hoja `estilos.css` tengo bastante código, no será que por eso no puedo ver las propiedades en el navegador, ni cuando subo los cambios.

Comment: Hola, debes ser un poco más específica, te sugiero dar una vuelta por [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y por [poner un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder ayudarte mejor. Ahora, con respecto a lo que mencionas, intentaste colocando esos códigos al final de tu hoja css, agregales el **! important** para que los reconozcan por sobre los otros estilos y no olvides limpiar la caché al momento de revisar tus cambios.

Comment: pon el fragmento de `html` donde cargas el `CSS` para poder ver si los cargaste correctamente

Comment: creo q una solución seria colocarla al **inicio de las lineas de codigo del css**
ya que seria como estilos base de tu pagina

Comment: Hola, tal y como te ha comentado @BrunoEchevarríaQuiroga sería muy bueno que indicarás un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible. Por otro lado, te sugiero que revises el orden en el que estás importando el CSS, ya que este también es muy importante. Por último, no abuses del uso de `!important` (recomendación de Bruno), ya que te puede generar problemas. Puedes [consultarlo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)

Comment: hola amigos ya me los reconoción el problema esque lo estaba agregando al final, como saber el orden correcto  ?

Comment: @AlexandraLoor Agrega siempre los estilos de las librerías primero teniendo en cuenta que si una librería utiliza los estilos de otra, esta otra tendrá que estar la primera. Y por último agrega tus estilos. De esta manera, si por algún casual los estilos que hayas personalizado entraran en conflicto con alguno de los de las librerías y tuvieran la misma [especificidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css), los tuyos prevalecerían por el modelo en cascada que sigue CSS.

Comment: ¿cuál seria un ejemplo de estilos de librería?

Answer (score 2):

Resulta que en tu archivo `estilos.css`, la sección que tienes el código que adjuntas, esta dentro de una media query

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  iframe { 
    width: 100%;
  }

h2{
    text-align: center;
}
 p {
    font-family: Sans-serif;
  }
```

si redimencionas el navegador a 800px o menos se verán tus estilos.

Solo debes cerrar la ambas media querys(idealmente quitar una) quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
 @media (max-width: 800px){
  .mobile{ 
    width: 100%;
  }
  iframe { 
    width: 100%;
  }
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    font-family: Sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes los estilos que tiene y que están dentro de un media query? En el código de la pregunta o la información de los comentarios no se hace referencia a nada de eso

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cuando publico la pregunta tenia un link hacia su sitio y revise el fichero `estilos.css` vi el error, iba a dejarle un comentario pero preferí dejarle la respuesta.

Comment: Mira que vi las revisiones, pero se me pasó el enlace al final. Buen ojo.