# No se aplica media-query en elemento en móvil

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy haciendo un `div` tipo "Modal" de Bootstrap. Todo funciona bien, he centrado la caja cuando se consulta en escritorio y debería de pasar lo mismo cuando es consultado en un teléfono. He puesto una sentencia `left:33%` en CSS para centrarlo y cuando sea un dispositivo móvil sea un `left:0`, pero no me está resultando: cuando es escritorio no hay problema, pero cuando es móvil el `div` se sale de la pantalla. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```css
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  #infoWindow {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1%;
  }
}

#infoWindow {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 33%;
  padding: 1%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoWindow" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h4 class="text-center"></h4>
  <p></p>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-md" id="closeInfo" value="Cerrar">
</div>
```

Comment: Relacionado también: [¿Qué es y para que se utiliza la especificidad de CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En CSS el orden de las reglas puede afectar el resultado. Cuando el navegador procesa el CSS, calcula la [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) de cada una de ellas y si el mismo elemento tiene varias reglas diferentes que le afectan, se dará prioridad a la que sea más específica.

Ahora, si dos reglas tienen la misma especificidad (como es el caso), entonces se aplicará la que aparezca más tarde en el código. En tu código la media query aparece primero y luego viene una sin nada (solo el id del elemento), por lo que se aplicará esa última en caso de conflicto, creando el problema que ves.

La solución entonces es mover la media query al final:

```css
#infoWindow {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 33%;
  padding: 1%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  #infoWindow {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoWindow" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h4 class="text-center"></h4>
  <p></p>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-md" id="closeInfo" value="Cerrar">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias sensei.