# Quitar separacion entre celdas

Tags: css, html5

¿Cómo puedo quitar o bien juntar más esa separación que hay entre los botones y entre los dos enlaces?

Esta separación que marco con flechas (he aumentado la imagen para que se vea mejor).

[image: separación que deseo eliminar]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Textos</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 
      <style type="text/css">
        a{
              display:block;
              text-decoration:none;
              }
       body {  
             background-color: white;
             background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
             background-size: cover;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;  
             background-attachment: fixed; 
           }
        .texto1{
          font-size:70px; 
          text-shadow: 2px 2px  10px black, 0 0 0 white, 0 0 0.2em grey; color: black;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
        .texto2{
          font-size:50px; 
          text-shadow: 2px 2px  10px black, 0 0 0 white, 0 0 0.2em grey; color: Red;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
            }

  table, tr, td {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   border: 0
   border-collapse: collapse; 
   } 

    </style>
  
 </head>
<body>

<!-- <div> -->
  <div >
          <p>
          <p>

          <div>
            <a href="#info1" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Primero</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info1" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto1">Texto 1</p>
            <p class="texto2">Texto 1</p>
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <a href="#info2" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Segundo</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info2" class="oculto">
                <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 ">
                           <tr>
                               <td ><span style="font: 15pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;»</span></td>
                               <td ><a href="http://www.prueba.com">Tema 1</a></td>
                           <tr> 
                          <tr>
                             <td ><span style="font: 15pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;»</span></td>
                             <td ><a href="http://www.prueba.com">Tema 2</a></td>
                          </tr>
                </table>
          </div>
         
          <div>
             <a href="#info3" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Trecero</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info3" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto1">Texto 3</p>
          </div>
          
          <div>
           <a href="#info4" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Cuarto</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info4" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto2">Texto 4</p>
          </div>

          <div>
           <a href="#info5" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Quinto</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info5" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto2">Texto 5</p>
          </div>
  </div>
<!-- </div> -->



<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".oculto").hide();              
    $(".inf").click(function(){
          var nodo = $(this).attr("href");  
 
          if ($(nodo).is(":visible")){
               $(nodo).hide();
               return false;
          }else{
        $(".oculto").hide("slow");                             
        $(nodo).fadeToggle("fast");
        return false;
          }
    });
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar también los estilos que tienes actualmente? Ahora mismo no parece que haya un gran espacio entre los textos en el ejemplo que has proporcionado.

Comment: Hola Francisco, te he puesto todos los estilos que tengo en el primer post, hay partes en los que pongo un texto con esos estilos, te lo pongo igualmente aunque no este puesto en esos enlaces que intento juntar.

Comment: Si utilizas Cntrl+M puedes agregar el HTML y CSS para que se puedan visualizar juntos en la página como un conjunto (como si los ejecutaras desde tu navegador). Te recomiendo editar la pregunta para que se vea mucho más claro tu problema. Gracias :)

Comment: te he puesto todo el codigo con el que estoy probando

Comment: Entonces el codigo ya te lo has podido copiar.

Comment: Sí, perdona. Lo he estado mirando antes buscando alguna solución pero me he tenido que ir. Por lo que veo tu `td` agrega un espacio por arriba y por abajo y estoy intentando saber por que aunque sospecho que es por la fuente que le pones al `>>`. Veo que en tu imagen el espacio es más pronunciado que en lo que se muestra en el ejemplo del snippet. Entiendo que será por que lo has aumentado y no porque haya otros estilos diferentes, ¿verdad?

Comment: No Francisco, solo puse el comentario como recordatorio, me imagino que por la hora que era estábamos a punto de ir a comer, jeje, y si, parece que has dado con el problema, dichoso signo, llevo todo el día liado y con me dije en él, di por hecho que ese tamaño seria el mismo que la altura del texto, y parece que no es así, buscare otro, o bien lo capturare y creare una imagen recortando el tamaño, a ver si así funciona,  muchas gracias Francisco.

Comment: Lo que no se es porque a la hora de poner una imagen se crea esa separacion mira la imagen con el codigo http://funkyimg.com/i/2De6L.png

Comment: Te estoy redactando una respuesta con una posible solución. Dame 5 minutos para terminar de redactarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como el problema parece que es la fuente que le has asociado al "icono" `>>` te sugiero utilizar la librería **[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)** la cual te proporciona iconos que se tratan como si fueran texto (puedes agrandarlos, cambiarles el color, ponerlos en negrita, etc).

En este caso, he utilizado el icono siguiente:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Por lo tanto, el icono ya lo tienes hecho, simplemente lo tendrás que ajustar al tamaño en el que quieras mostrarlo y... voilá!

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Textos</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        a{
              display:block;
              text-decoration:none;
              }
       body {  
             background-color: white;
             background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
             background-size: cover;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;  
             background-attachment: fixed; 
           }
        .texto1{
          font-size:70px; 
          text-shadow: 2px 2px  10px black, 0 0 0 white, 0 0 0.2em grey; color: black;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
        .texto2{
          font-size:50px; 
          text-shadow: 2px 2px  10px black, 0 0 0 white, 0 0 0.2em grey; color: Red;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
            }

  table, tr, td {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   border: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse; 
   } 

    </style>
  
 </head>
<body>

<!-- <div> -->
  <div >
          <p>
          <p>

          <div>
            <a href="#info1" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Primero</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info1" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto1">Texto 1</p>
            <p class="texto2">Texto 1</p>
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <a href="#info2" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Segundo</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info2" class="oculto">
                <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                           <tr>
                               <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
                               <td ><a href="http://www.prueba.com">Tema 1</a></td>
                           <tr> 
                          <tr>
                             <td ><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
                             <td ><a href="http://www.prueba.com">Tema 2</a></td>
                          </tr>
                </table>
          </div>
         
          <div>
             <a href="#info3" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Trecero</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info3" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto1">Texto 3</p>
          </div>
          
          <div>
           <a href="#info4" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Cuarto</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info4" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto2">Texto 4</p>
          </div>

          <div>
           <a href="#info5" class="inf"><button type="button" style='width:150px; text-align: left'>Libro Quinto</button></a>
          </div>
          <div id="info5" class="oculto">
            <p class="texto2">Texto 5</p>
          </div>
  </div>
<!-- </div> -->



<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".oculto").hide();              
    $(".inf").click(function(){
          var nodo = $(this).attr("href");  
 
          if ($(nodo).is(":visible")){
               $(nodo).hide();
               return false;
          }else{
        $(".oculto").hide("slow");                             
        $(nodo).fadeToggle("fast");
        return false;
          }
    });
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**NOTA:** He visto que tienes dos errores en tu HTML y CSS:

1) Te falta un `;` al final de `border: 0` cuando se lo aplicas a los elementos table, tr y td.

2) Tienes un `"` sobrante en la línea en la que defines tu tabla, justo aquí `cellpadding=0 "`, deberías quitarlo.

**NOTA 2**: **Nunca** (o casi nunca) **uses estilos inline**, debido a que luego son muy difíciles de mantener. Si quieres más información, puedes leer sobre esta auto pregunta-respuesta mía que realicé sobre la **[especificidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css)** en CSS.

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias Francisco, esos errores son cometidos por las prisas que no son buenas, jeje, estaba probando con diferentes soluciones, y se quedaron por el camino, lo que dices de utilizar estilos inline te refieres al **jquery-2.1.4.js** lo puse para que funcionase el código, tengo guardado el archivo, porque intento que las paginas se utilicen en local, por eso te iba a preguntar si el archivo **all.js** lo podía utilizar también en local,

Comment: @SoCu No, con estilos inline me refiero a indicar en los elementos el atributo `style`. Puedes ver un ejemplo de porque da problemas en el ejemplo `Ejemplo de estilos inline sobre un ID` de la respuesta que he referenciado. Por otro lado, no debes de confundir el CSS con los scripts de Javascript. Cuando hablamos de estilos nos referimos al CSS, y por lo tanto, cuando nos referimos a estilos inline, solo hace referencia a los elementos a los que les aplicas el atributo `style`. Y por último, todos los ficheros .js los puedes descargar y referenciarlos desde tu ruta local/servidor.

Comment: @SoCu De esta manera, aunque hubiera un problema con la página original en la que se encuentran dichos ficheros, tu página seguiría funcionando ya que tendrías los recursos a tu alcance.

Comment: Cracias, estaba biendo el enlace que has puesto a tu otro post sobre **#parrafo{}** y **.parrafo{}**

Comment: @SoCu Son IDs y clases, respectivamente. Es bueno tener clara esa diferencia. De hecho, es mucho mejor utilizar clases que los valores de las etiquetas (p.ej: `table`, `tr`, `td`, `span`, etc...) si vas a usar un estilo en más de un elemento debido a que si utilizas los nombres de las etiquetas, si quisieras por ejemplo tener dos tablas con estilos diferentes, adoptarían los mismos estilos ya que los estarías aplicando a todas las etiquetas que fueran iguales. Si tienes cualquier duda, no dudes en preguntar o, en caso de que sea un nuevo problema, realizar una nueva pregunta :)

Comment: Para no alargar mas este post, he crado uno nuevo sobre la libreria aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145104/como-utilizar-la-libreria-font-awesome por si quieres responder en ese post