# Asignar color HTML a fórmula JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Quisiera saber que puedo hacer para colocar en el formulario de Javascript un color HTML, por ahora me toma los colores de las clases, pero deseo que sea directamente sobre el HTML.

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($("#dpm").offset().top > 56) {
            $("#dpm").addClass("deep-purple lighten-5");
            $("a").addClass("text-primary");
        } else {
            $("#dpm").removeClass("deep-purple lighten-5");
            $("a").removeClass("text-primary");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Cuando utilizo las clases, todo me sale bien, pero si creo una clase modificada en CSS, no tiene efecto y no se como poner en la parte del texto el CSS, es decir:
 `$("a").removeClass("#ffffff");` por ejemplo, para que me tome ese color en HTML el texto.

Comment: Lo que he entendio es que quieres cambiar el color. Pero para ello vas a necesitar css. En JQuery hay una función llamada `.css`. Ejemplo: `$("#dpm").css("color","red");`. Esto añadirá en la etiqueta `style` de HTML el color

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es modificar el color de un elemento directamente en el HTML (cosa que no te recomiendo) mediante Javascript lo podrás hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById("dpm").style.color = "red";
```

Y como te han comentado también lo puedes realizar con JQuery de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#dpm").css("color","red");
```

En ambos casos se modifica el atributo `style` del elemento seleccionado.

**Aclaración:** Te recomiendo no utilizar estos métodos a no ser que sea por imposibilidad de modificar el HTML y que ese HTML contenga elementos con el atributo `style`, es decir, si puedes modificar el HTML, te recomiendo quitar de todos los elementos dicho atributo y utilizar ids o clases en su defecto para agregar tus estilos CSS. Esto te permitirá tener un mejor mantenimiento del sitio debido a que los ids o clases contienen una menor **[especificidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122039/qu%C3%A9-es-y-para-que-se-utiliza-la-especificidad-de-css/122040#122040)** y por lo tanto son mucho más fáciles de sobrescribir.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, realmente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el menu este fijo este de color transparente y cuando se desplace, se le asigne un color.

Comment: Al ser una pregunta distinta, te recomiendo que vuelvas a formular otra pregunta esta vez con un ejemplo mínimo verificable para poderte ayudar mejor.  De esta manera, te podremos ayudar mucho mejor @EricRuiz